# Microsoft graph api search doesn't return all files

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sites

I have a folder hierarchy in OneDrive containing around 1000 files spread out under those folders. All files are .mp4 files.
When I do a search using the graph api and specify q='.mp4' it returns only 500 files (paged with 200 in each page). I have tried using $top=1000 but then I get one page only with 500 files.

Is there a limit of 500 for the search?

Comment: If you're using $top then it accepts a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 999 (inclusive). Here's the related doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter

Comment: I tried with 999 but still only get 500.

Comment: You see this behavior only with onedrive items?

Comment: I have only tried with OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue during a customers project, where I requested the users group membership using Microsoft Graph.

For me, the solution was to use the $top parameter as you already mentioned.

GET
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/?$top=999

I am not aware if there is any kind of limitation or difference as soon as you use the OneDrive Graph endpoint.

Comment: I tried with 999 but still I get only 500. And no nextlink.

Comment: If its the case, just make sure you have more than 500+ items so it can return. You can test the above using Microsoft Graph explorer as well. If you still face issue or no nextlink, consider filing a support ticket with Microsoft support for further help.